# Identify storage devices in a network

Tags: networking, online-storage, nmap

I am scanning a network looking for storage devices with nmap. Any ideas on which I should base my search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for any device or computer that has file sharing (smb) enabled? The microsoft file and printer sharing protocol needs port 445 to be open. This command lists anything on the network with port 445 open (you'll have to change the IP range for your network).

nmap -open -p 445 192.168.10.*